# export folders list in specific pattern PowerShell

Tags: list, powershell, export

I need to export a list of folders in a specific pattern
my code is

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\test\  -Directory | Select-Object BaseName
```

I need the final output to be.

```
<object> folder name here </object>
```

so I can use it later to update an xml file I have

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = Get-ChildItem -Path d:\tmp\  -Directory | Select-Object @{name="baseNameInTag"; expression = {"<object>{0}</object>" -f $_.BaseName}}
```

[Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 0):

- Use [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) to get all `.BaseName` values from the output objects emitted by [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).

  - As an aside: For directories, `.BaseName` is - perhaps surprisingly - the same as `.Name` - only for *files* is an extension, if present, removed.
- Use [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) to embed each base name in (the string representation of) an XML element using an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```bash
(Get-ChildItem -Directory c:\test).BaseName |
  ForEach-Object { "<object>$_</object>" }
```